# How to update cell values using conditions and a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying update a specific number in a column. This number should be determined following a comparison of the values of another column with fixed ones. A loop should repeat this process for the entire column.

```vb
Sub comparison()

    Dim Cell As Range
   
    For Each Cell In Range("I2", Range("I2").End(xlDown))
        If Cell > 3000000 Then
            Cell.Offset(, -2).Value = 75
        ElseIf 1000000 < Cell < 3000000 Then
            Cell.Offset(, -2).Value = 100
        ElseIf 100000 < Cell < 1000000 Then
            Cell.Offset(, -2).Value = 200
        ElseIf Cell < 100000 Then
            Cell.Offset(, -2).Value = 300
        End If
    Next Cell
        
End Sub
```

Comment: `1000000 < Cell < 3000000` ... you need `And`. VBA doesn't do `... < ... < ...` like you think. Or use `Select Case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Cell` is a reserved word in Excel. You cannot use reserved words as variable names.
2. The cases are ordered, if you have already established that something is less than a number, you don't need to say it again.
3. Select Case has a `To` that can be used to cover a range of numbers

Using these principals your code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub comparison()

    Dim thisCell As Range
    For Each thisCell In Range("I2", Range("I2").End(xlDown))
        Select Case thisCell.Value
        Case Is > 3000000
            thisCell.Offset(, -2).Value = 75
        Case 3000000 To 1000000
            thisCell.Offset(, -2).Value = 100
        Case 1000000 To 100000
            thisCell.Offset(, -2).Value = 200
        Case Is < 100000
            thisCell.Offset(, -2).Value = 300
        End Select
    Next thisCell
        
End Sub
```

Comment: *Cell* is not even a keyword. *Value* is a keyword and it is **recommended** to not use it but many still do. *To* is a reserved keyword and you cannot use it. Related to the Select Case statement, Microsoft states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement): *"If you use the To keyword, the smaller value must appear before To."* i.e. the 100s and 200s are not being populated.

Answer (score 1):

### Column Values in Range (Math)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateColumn() ' this is also bad; make it more descriptive (personalized)
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ' If it's in the workbook containing this code and you know its name,
    ' then reference it explicitly instead, e.g.:
    'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Reference the source one-column range.
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = ws.Range("I2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
    
    ' Reference the destination one-column range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns("G")
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sCellValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dResult As Double
    
    ' Reference each source cell...
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        ' ... and store its value.
        sCellValue = sCell.Value
        ' Increase the row index by 1...
        r = r + 1
        ' ... to reference the destination cell.
        Set dCell = drg.Cells(r)
        ' Check if the source value is a number.
        If VarType(sCellValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            ' Determine the destination result.
            Select Case sCellValue
                Case Is < 100000: dResult = 300
                Case Is < 1000000: dResult = 200
                Case Is < 3000000: dResult = 100
                Case Else: dResult = 75
            End Select
            ' Write the result to the destination cell.
            dCell.Value = dResult
        Else ' is not a number
            ' Clear the contents of the destination cell.
            dCell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next sCell
        
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Column populated.", vbInformation
        
End Sub
```